# Implementing methods for CSS Regions

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css

I was playing around with CSS regions: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-regions-20120503/

```
document.webkitGetFlowByName("myFlow")
=> WebKitNamedFlow
```

However, none of the JavaScript API/methods work. This might be a naive question, but I'm really interested in using the proposed JavaScript API. Any thoughts on how one might implement it? This presentation page highlights the specific methods for named flows that I'd love to use: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5-therealbleedingedge/template/index.html#13

Thank you!

Comment: this is some early adopter type material...just out of curiosity what are you using regions for...the example show a newspaper like spread.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist I was using it to try and paginate stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS Regions development is still a work in progress.

The latest updates are currently available only in [WebKit nightly builds](http://nightly.webkit.org/). If you're using Google Chrome, please note that CSS Regions needs to be manually enabled. Type "about://flags" in the address bar, enable the CSS Regions flag and relaunch the browser.

Google Chrome has some features trickled in but most are in an intermediate state because of the Webkit forking schedule Google has.

You can run the [CSS Regions feature detection tests](http://adobe.github.com/web-platform/utilities/css-regions-feature-testing/) and see what's working on your environment.

At this point CSS Regions is still in development and some features will change slightly in the coming weeks.

The [CSS Regions samples](http://adobe.github.com/web-platform/samples/css-regions/) may help you experiment with the features. The samples are all expected to work with the latest Webkit nightly build.